# Determining a bivariate function from its integrals

Tags: integration, functions

Essentially, my question is: what is $f(x,y)$ such that 
$$
\int f(x,y)dx\ = (1-y)\times f(x,y) 
$$
and 
$$
\int f(x,y)dy\ = x\times f(x,y)
$$
I've been struggling with the proper approach to this, any pointers are appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By [the fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), we can write
$$f(x,y)=(1-y)\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=x\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\tag{*}$$
And one can solve linear pde
$$(y-1)\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$$
to obtain $f(x,y)=\Phi(x^2-y^2+2y)$, where $\Phi$ is smooth one-variable function to be determined from equation $(*)$. Plug $f$ into the equation,
$$2x(1-y)\frac{d\Phi(s)}{ds}=\Phi(s)$$
where $s=x^2-y^2+2y$. Unfortunately, $2x(1-y)$ cannot be expressed as function of $s$.

In other way, if you solve two odes from $(*)$ respectively and obtain two partial solutions $f(x,y)=\exp\{\frac{x}{1-y}+C_1(y)\}$ and $f(x,y)=\exp\{\frac{y}{x}+C_2(x)\}$, still we cannot find such $C_1,C_2$ to make two partial solutions consistent.

In conclusion, there's no such function $f(x,y)$ that satisfies given integral equations.